# Can IrfanView manipulate an image buffer?

Tags: image-processing, image-manipulation

It can manipulate images stored on file system, but can it take in an image buffer?

Else, what other options or free SDKs can I use to manipulate an image buffer? In particular, rotation.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org) -- it can take a buffer directly.

You didn't say what language/framework you use.  For .NET look at Atalasoft's [DotImage Photo](http://www.atalasoft.com/free-dotnet-image-sdk), which is free (disclaimer: I work at Atalasoft).